# How can I provide links to intranet files through ASP.net?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

Conditions:
The files must be opened outside of the window that the link to them is in.

I have tried href, but when I give it an intranet link it only opens correctly if I leave out target="_blank"; if I put that in, the new window that opens doesn't receive the full link if there is a pound sign in the filepath... a direct link to the intranet address \a\b\c#c.txt would be fine with me; there is no concern about security, but I can't seem to get that to happen in a new window. It seems like this is happening when I don't create a new window, but I can't utilize the same window to open the links.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please post relevant source code (including related scripts).  It could be a JavaScript issue.

Comment: I am doing this purely with C#, haven't written any scripts. I populate a placeholder dynamically with Labels, iterating over a collection of file names...

Label l = new Label();
l.ID = "hyperLink" + idx.ToString();
l.Text = "<a href=\"" + Global.AttachmentHyperlinkLocation + requestID.ToString() + "/" + UploadedAttachments[idx] + "\" target=\"_blank\">" + UploadedAttachments[idx] + "</a>";

Comment: Can you post a sample of one of the problematic link URLs?  I notice your example in the question has the slashes backwards, and I assume you know that the # sign marks a fragment identifier (http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_2_Fragments.html).

Comment: When I click the link generated by the code above, I see the following in the new window's address bar (edited): "\\server\application\Temp\3cq4vuiduxymvze1db0magvy\tes", where tes should be tes#t.txt. The application's link to opening that file, seen in IE when I hover over the href, is file://server/application/Temp/SessionID/tes#t.txt . I know that the # is unacceptable for a URL, but I've tried some of the encoding functions in .NET and they break the link in one way or another. Do I have to write my own encoding function? Oh, and I believe you are noticing an escape slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack but try changing the links to href="#" onclick="window.open('http://' + escape(restofurl))"

Comment: Even after trying that, clicking the link which opens a new window shows the whole correct link for a moment in the address bar (just a quick flash) while opening before changing to the link to everything up to (but not including) the '#' and then failing. Perhaps I'm having a browser issue...?

Comment: If the link starts out correct then changes it sounds like your bit is working and something else is changing it.
You are either having a browser issue or there is some kind of further redirect in the page you are redirecting to.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can get the link to work, the user accessing it may or may not have rights to see that machine.

What I do in cases where I have to link to other files on other server, is link to a generic handler(.ashx file) that does impersonation of user that does have rights, or impersonates the logged-in user. The handler then reads the contents of the file and streams it to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried streaming the file contents to the browser?